# Hex bitwise operation in c++

Tags: c++, binary, hex, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles

By using filestreaming in c++, I have read a string in the binary file into a buffer (4 bytes). I know that the buffer contains "`89abcdef`". The buffer is such that:

```
buffer[0] = 89
buffer[1] = ab
buffer[2] = cd
buffer[3] = ef
```

Now, I want to recover these numbers into one single hex number `0x89abcdef`. However, this is not as simple as I thought. I tried the following code:

```
int num = 0;
num |= buffer[0];
num <<= 24;
cout << num << endl;
```

at this point, `num` is displayed to be

```
ea000000
```

When I tried the same algorithm for the second element of the buffer:

```
num = 0;
num |= buffer[1];
num <<= 16;
cout << num << endl;
```

output:

```
ffcd0000
```

The `ff` in front of the `cd` is highly inconvenient for me to add them all together (I was planning to make it something looks like `00cd0000`, and add it to the first `num`).

Could anyone help me to recover the hex number `0x89abcdef`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't modify the actual number until the end:

```
num = buffer [0] << 24 | buffer [1] << 16 | buffer [2] << 8 | buffer [3];
```

`buffer [0] << 24` gives you your first result, which is combined with the second result independent of the first, and so on.

Also, as pointed out, operations like this should be done on unsigned numbers, so that the signing doesn't interfere with the result.

Comment: And using `unsigned` integers would be best, as the _unsigned shift arithmetics_ don't have _sign-extension_ and other issues.

Comment: @K-ballo, Definitely, I didn't notice that a signed one was being used.

Comment: The output of your code is:
`ffffffef`
I had this output before, that is why I came to this website for help...BTW, this output is on top of your suggestion, which is using unsigned int type.

Comment: @return0, Could you post a complete sample of how you're using it? It prints out correctly for me.

Comment: @chris yea, i tried to output using `cout << hex << num;` it still outputs `ffffffef`...

Comment: @chris I see the problem, my buffer is declared as char *buffer, what should I do if it is not a int type array?

Comment: @return0, you can use `unsigned char`, or `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 2):

For all of your bitwise operations, you're going to want to use unsigned int instead of int. This way you can avoid the kinds of sign-extension problems you're seeing.